# When I go back to the page, changing number and cell datas of the TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using nested tableview. The main tableview lists the file categories. Child tableview listing the files. I open the files with safari. The child tableview is listed incorrectly when I go back to the page after opening the file. How can i solve this problem? Android sdk have "onActivityResult" method. Does iOS have a similar function? Thanks.

#### ViewController

```
import UIKit


class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var bundleProductModel:ProductModel? = ProductModel.init()
    var lastFileCatIndex:Int = 0

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // If tableview is file category table.
        if (tableView.tag == 100){
            return bundleProductModel!.fileCategoryModels.count
        } else /* Table view is file tableview. */ {
            //self.lastFileIndex = self.lastFileIndex + 1
            return (bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[self.lastFileCatIndex].files.count)!
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (tableView.tag == 100){

            // Define cell for file category.
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileCategoryTableViewCell") as! FileCategoryTableViewCell

            // Set file category cell height.
            cell.frame.size.height = CGFloat(((bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[indexPath.row].files.count)! * 44) + 42)

            // cell row height
            tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(((bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[indexPath.row].files.count)! * 44) + 42)

            // Control bound
            if (self.lastFileCatIndex <= indexPath.row){

                // Index.
                self.lastFileCatIndex = indexPath.row

                // File category name.
                cell.lblFileCatNme.text = "   \(bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[indexPath.row].file_category_name ?? "Unknow")   "

            }

            return cell
        } else {
            // Define cell for files.
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileTableViewCell") as! FileTableViewCell

            if ((bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[self.lastFileCatIndex].files.count)! > indexPath.row){

                // Set file model to file cell.
                cell.setFile(fileItem: (self.bundleProductModel?.fileCategoryModels[self.lastFileCatIndex].files[indexPath.row])!)

                // file cell delegate
                cell.delegate = self

            } else {
                cell.lblFileName.text = "unknow"
            }

            return cell
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

extension ProductDetailViewController:FileCellDelegate{

    func didClickDownload(downloadLink: String, button: UIButton) {
        if let url = URL(string: downloadLink) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to change? Are you trying to remove a row if the user tapped it?

Comment: No. I release the safari when the user presses it. When the user came back to the page, the child tableviews are sorted incorrectly. I found the problem; The lastFileCategoryIndex variable. Ex: final value is four. When I come back to the page; listing relative to fourth index. I need define child tableview in main tableview cell.

Comment: Why is `bundleProductModel` optional?

Comment: Because i send value in segue from previous viewcontroller.

Comment: If you send a value in the segue then there is more than ever no need to declare  `bundleProductModel` as optional. Non-optional values can never crash and you get rid of a lot of question and exclamation marks.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very easy workaround on iOS would be to override `viewWillAppear` and call `reloadData()` like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will update your table everytime your view reappears.

Answer (score 1):

### SOLVED

Problem is lastFileCategoryIndex variable. Ex: final value is four. When I come back to the page; listing relative to fourth index. I define child tableview in main tableview cell and solved.

#### FileCategoryTableViewCell

```
class FileCategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // General Objects
    var fileCategoryModel:FileCategoryModel = FileCategoryModel.init()

    // Cell Ui Objects
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFileCatNme: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fileTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fileCategoryModel.files.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = fileTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileTableViewCell") as! FileTableViewCell
        cell.lblFileName.text = "Ex File..."
        return cell
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    // Set category model.
    func setFileCategory(fileCategoryModel:FileCategoryModel){
        self.fileCategoryModel = fileCategoryModel

        self.fileTableView.dataSource = self
        self.fileTableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```